# GRANT command not working on MySQL 8.0.25

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I'm attempting to grant a user privileges within a database, and I'm receiving the error

```
#1410 - You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

I'm executing the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

The user is already created, but I cannot grant privileges to it.

Below is an example of a user I'm attempting to edit.
[image: User Reference]

Comment: I've checked for typos, I seem to be entering all the information correctly.

Comment: What does this say:  `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conflicting authentication settings on users were preventing the user from registering properly. Deleted all affected users and created them again.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for MySQL 5.7 states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html):

> Use of GRANT to define account authentication characteristics is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6. Instead, establish or change authentication characteristics using CREATE USER or ALTER USER. This GRANT capability will be removed in a future MySQL release.

Instead [you need to `CREATE USER` then `GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html):

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: he uses mysql 8

Comment: Regardless, after the ```CREATE``` command is used, the ```GRANT``` command refused to apply to that freshly created user.